# To infinity and beyond in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, infinity

In JavaScript there is a global property named `Infinity`, and to the best of my knowledge the value of `Infinity` is `1.797693134862315E+308` (I may be wrong there).
I also understand that any number larger than `1.797693134862315E+308` is considered a *"bad number"*, if this is the case then why does my code (below) work perfectly fine?

This is my code:

```
// Largest number in JavaScript = "1.797693134862315E+308"
// Buzz = Infinity + "0.1"
var buzz = 1.897693134862315E+308;

// Why is no error is thrown, even though the value of "buzz" is a bad number...
if(buzz >= Infinity) {
  console.log("To infinity and beyond.");
}
```

The output is:

```
=> "To infinity and beyond."
```

There is a working example of my code on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/FQyQ/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The value of `Infinity` is `Infinity`. It is not the number you mention, which is `Number.MAX_VALUE`. `Infinity` is a constant that has meaning in the number system.
2. Adding a small number to a large floating-point value doesn't overflow because the number **is** a large floating-point value and that's how floating point works. If you add a large enough number to a large number, as in

   ```
   Number.MAX_VALUE + Number.MAX_VALUE
   ```

   then it *will* overflow and you'll get `Infinity`.

You can [read more about IEEE 754 Floating Point math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) on Wikipedia or various other sources.